# Manually generate IdentityServer4 reference token and save to PersistedGrants table

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.1

I have learnt `IdentityServer4` for a week and successfully implemented a simple authentication flow with `ResourceOwnedPassword` flow.

Now, I'm implementing **Google authentication with IdentityServer4** by following [this tutorial](https://www.blinkingcaret.com/2017/05/03/external-login-providers-in-asp-net-core/)

This is what I am doing:

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //...

    const string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=IdentityServer4.Quickstart.EntityFramework-2.0.0;trusted_connection=yes;";
    var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

    services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
        .AddProfileService<IdentityServerProfileService>()
        .AddResourceOwnerValidator<IdentityResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>()
        // this adds the config data from DB (clients, resources)
        .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
        {
            options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
            {
                builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                    sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
            };

        })
        // this adds the operational data from DB (codes, tokens, consents)
        .AddOperationalStore(options =>
        {
            options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                    sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
            // this enables automatic token cleanup. this is optional.
            options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
            options.TokenCleanupInterval = 30;
        });

    // Add jwt validation.
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
        {
            // base-address of your identityserver
            options.Authority = "https://localhost:44386";

            options.ClaimsIssuer = "https://localhost:44386";

            // name of the API resource
            options.ApiName = "api1";
            options.ApiSecret = "secret";

            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

            options.SupportedTokens = SupportedTokens.Reference;

        });

    //...
}
```

** Google controller (Which is for handling returned token from Google **

```
public class GLoginController : Controller
    {
        #region Properties

        private readonly IPersistedGrantStore _persistedGrantStore;

        private readonly IUserFactory _userFactory;

        private readonly IBaseTimeService _baseTimeService;

        private readonly ITokenCreationService _tokenCreationService;

        private readonly IReferenceTokenStore _referenceTokenStore;

        private readonly IBaseEncryptionService _baseEncryptionService;

        #endregion

        #region Constructor

        public GLoginController(IPersistedGrantStore persistedGrantStore,
            IBaseTimeService basetimeService,
            ITokenCreationService tokenCreationService,
            IReferenceTokenStore referenceTokenStore,
            IBaseEncryptionService baseEncryptionService,
            IUserFactory userFactory)
        {
            _persistedGrantStore = persistedGrantStore;
            _baseTimeService = basetimeService;
            _userFactory = userFactory;
            _tokenCreationService = tokenCreationService;
            _referenceTokenStore = referenceTokenStore;
            _baseEncryptionService = baseEncryptionService;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        [HttpGet("login")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            var authenticationProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = "/api/google/handle-external-login"
            };

            return Challenge(authenticationProperties, "Google");
        }

        [HttpGet("handle-external-login")]
        //[Authorize("ExternalCookie")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> HandleExternalLogin()
        {
            //Here we can retrieve the claims
            var authenticationResult = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);
            var principal = authenticationResult.Principal;

            var emailAddress = principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(emailAddress))
                return NotFound(new ApiMessageViewModel("Email is not found"));

            // Find user by using username.
            var loadUserConditions = new LoadUserModel();
            loadUserConditions.Usernames = new HashSet<string> { emailAddress };
            loadUserConditions.Pagination = new PaginationValueObject(1, 1);

            // Find users asynchronously.
            var loadUsersResult = await _userFactory.FindUsersAsync(loadUserConditions);
            var user = loadUsersResult.FirstOrDefault();

            // User is not defined.
            if (user == null)
            {
                user = new User(Guid.NewGuid(), emailAddress);
                user.Email = emailAddress;
                user.HashedPassword = _baseEncryptionService.Md5Hash("abcde12345-");
                user.JoinedTime = _baseTimeService.DateTimeUtcToUnix(DateTime.UtcNow);
                user.Kind = UserKinds.Google;
                user.Status = UserStatuses.Active;

                //await _userFactory.AddUserAsync(user);
            }
            else
            {
                // User is not google account.
                if (user.Kind != UserKinds.Google)
                    return Forbid("User is not allowed to access system.");
            }

            var token = new Token(IdentityServerConstants.TokenTypes.IdentityToken);
            var userCredential = new UserCredential(user);

            token.Claims = userCredential.GetClaims();
            token.AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Reference;
            token.ClientId = "ro.client";
            token.CreationTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            token.Audiences = new[] {"api1"};
            token.Lifetime = 3600;


            return Ok();
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Everything is fine, I can get claims returned from **Google OAuth2**, find users in database using Google email address and register them if they dont have any acounts.

My question is: How can I use Google OAuth2 claims that I receive in `HandleExternalLogin` method to generate a **Reference Token**, save it to **PersistedGrants** table and return to client.

This means when user access `https://localhost:44386/api/google/login`, after being redirected to Google consent screen, they can receive `access_token`, `refresh_token` that has been generated by `IdentityServer4`.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

- In IdentityServer the kind (jwt of reference) of the token is
  configurable [for each client](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/reference_tokens.html) (application), requested the token.
- `AccessTokenType.Reference` is valid for `TokenTypes.AccessToken` not
  `TokenTypes.IdentityToken` as in your snippet.

In general it would be simpler to follow the [original quickstart](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/4_external_authentication.html) and then extend [the generic code](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/blob/master/Quickstart/Account/ExternalController.cs) up to your needs. What I can see now in the snippet above is just your specific stuff and not the default part, responsible for creating the IdSrv session and redirecting back to the client.

If you still like to create a token manually:

- inject `ITokenService` into your controller.
- fix the error I mentioned above: `TokenTypes.AccessToken` instead of <strike>`TokenTypes.IdentityToken`</strike>
- call `var tokenHandle = await TokenService.CreateAccessTokenAsync(token);`

`tokenHandle` is a key in `PersistedGrantStore`

Comment: I dont get your idea. I tried implementing [IdentityServer4 UI](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI) but they are using `in-memory` user store.

It is very frustrating to read the code again and again and find the way to customize it due to lack of detailed guideline.

Now, I just want to know whether I can generate `reference token` manually and save to `persistedgrantstore` or not.

Comment: Well, actually you asked a bit different thing. You asked how to combine external authentication with interactive flow with some non-interactive logic, and my advice is to avoid doing that. Look: you do not get any benefit of RO concept, as you redirect your user to Google anyway. So, it would be simpler for you to set the same grant type for your app as you already have defined for Google. Then you just set `AccessTokenType.Reference` in your client definition and that's it, no further coding needed.

Comment: And regarding `in-memory` user store: you are free to switch it in DI to the one based on Identity, or your own. Without over- or re-writing the overall logic.

Comment: Added the line of code, you most likely are looking for. `CreateAccessTokenAsync(token);` behaves depending on the `token.Type` and `token.AccessTokenType`. In case they are `OidcConstants.TokenTypes.AccessToken` and `AccessTokenType.Reference`, it stores the token.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. Let me give it a try